# Sibelius playback glitches

Tags: sibelius

I have several files in sibelius where playback either pauses on notes (in particular an upbeat into a second section) or plays with a lurching sort of effect with the strong/weak accents of normal music made a nonsense of. This last problem often resolves with a restart of the computer, so it isn't an issue of errors in the actual inputting.Anything obvious that I might have done wrong, or any suggestions for correcting this?

Comment: Any more info about the hardware you're using?

Comment: When I've run into similar issues, it's been performance problems with my audio setup. ASIO drivers did help things.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to show us the sib file.  Performance instructions can cause strange effects - e.g. the word 'Waltz' can cause notes to disappear.  On the main Sibelius forum we've just done troubleshooting on a score where the word 'cool' in a block of text had an unwanted playback effect.  Or this could be the characteristic lumpy playback of an inadequate audio system.   Come on over to [www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3](http://www.sibelius.com/cgi-bin/helpcenter/chat/chat.pl?groupid=3) , describe your hardware and attach a sib file, then those who know can help you.

Comment: "*On the main Sibelius forum we've just done troubleshooting on a score where the word 'cool' in a block of text had an unwanted playback effect.*" Wow. Makes me glad I'm not a Sibelius user. Also... this answer has a very comment-like feel. It asks for more information and refers the asker to another resource, but it doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox "Makes me glad I'm not a Sibelius user" - it's definitely too clever for its own good sometimes. The most confusing playback bug I've had was when the words "second time" *as part of the song title* were interpreted as a playback instruction!!!!